# Naming a model asset in Rails conflicts with pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I'm building out an API with Rails that has a few pages I may want to serve up for admin purposes.  One of the models I am serving up is called an `asset` because that's what it is.

The problem is that the routes all show properly when using `rake routes` and when getting assets from the API it's fine, but when I try to `PUT` to update the asset it fails with method not allowed.  I tried switching the name and Rails is just fine with anything else.

How can I get around this issue without renaming my model or using an alias route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can change rails assets path by providing prefix value in configuration like

```
config.assets.prefix = "/some_other_path"
```

Read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path)

Comment: I know this is from 2 years ago but if you're still out there, maybe you could help? I have a similar issue and this isn't cutting it. I provided more context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358404/rails-4-asset-pipeline-name-collision-with-model-asset).